# Non-journalled filesystem that allows instant power off?

Tags: filesystems

Is there a filesystem for Linux that allows for instant off via a power switch without going through a shutdown procedure? If so, would there be a significant performance hit compared to a journalled filesystem? And, could it support full-disk encryption?

The reason in part is that every distro I've installed on my laptop has resulted in problems with suspend/sleep and it seems that it would be faster with an ssd to just boot/halt.

Comment: Why do you *not* want a journaled filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. It's not safe to do an instant power-down in the middle of a disk write. Journalling can help in that situation, but it's still not a good thing to inflict on your HD on a regular basis.

Bear in mind that Linux does not write data to disk immediately - the Linux kernel caches filesystem reads and writes to improve performance, no matter which filesystem(s) you are using. I guess you could disable the caching (to a degree) but why degrade your system's performance merely to speed up shutdown?

Also, the HD (probably) has it own on-board buffering, and I expect that doesn't cope well with instant power-off, either. You can (probably) disable that buffering, too (using hdparm), But once again, this is inadvisable.

But if `shutdown -h now` (as root) isn't fast enough for you, and you want to experiment with instant power-down, you should at least send SIGTERM to all running processes to give them a chance to save data, and then run `sync` to tell the kernel to write cached data to disk before you hit the power switch.

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key for some more relevant info.

But maybe you should try instead to resolve whatever it is that's stopping your laptop from being able to suspend/sleep properly. I've heard that it is an issue for some machines, but maybe the experts here can help get this fixed for you.